# Example of a reflexive verb in Grothendieck's obituary

Tags: глаголы

In an obituary about Grothendieck at http://lenta.ru/news/2014/11/14/grothendieck/, the last paragraph says "... деятельность Института вышсих научных исследований, где работал ученый, частично финансируются военными,..." and I am not sure why it uses финансируются instead of финансируется. I would have thought this verb is governed by деятельность, which grammatically is singular ("the activity/work at IHES... is financed by...").

Comment: You are right. I think there were different versions like "научные исследования... финансируются военными", but then it was replaced by "деятельность" and "финансируются" was overlooked.

Comment: @Artemix +1. Since your comment answers the question, I think you should post it as an answer.

Comment: @Dmitry also, when a question is easily asnwered by a comment, it's typically not the best question :)

Comment: @shabunc: I agree the question is not profound, though I didn't want to find other questions on reflexive verbs in order to post my question as a comment itself.

Comment: @KCd oh actually nevermind, it is a totally valid question, moreover it's upvoted, thus, community find it interesting enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, it's a typo. Деятельность is in singular, therefore, финансируется. They've fixed it already.

Comment: Indeed they have. And now I see on Google that this page is one of the top hits when searching for "Grothendieck's obituary." Hmm...